# convert rows into coumns dinamiacally for some table with CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

by followed [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns on the basis of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns), 
I have 4 table to convert dinamiacally rows into columns as RESULT

TABLE A

```
| id |  stages |
-----+----------
| 1  | Stage A |
| 2  | Stage B |
| 3  | Stage C |
```

TABLE B

```
| id_b | code | lessons     |
-------+------+--------------
| 10   | FIS  | Physics     |
| 11   | MAT  | Mathematics |
| 12   | KIM  | Chemistry   |
| 13   | BIO  | Biology     |
```

TABLE C

```
|id_c|  students  |
-----+-------------
| 20 | student 20 |
| 21 | student 21 |
| 22 | student 22 |
| 23 | student 23 |
| 24 | student 24 |
| 25 | student 25 |
| 26 | student 26 |
| 27 | student 27 |
```

TABLE D

```
| id_d | id_a | id_b | id_c | value_m | value_n |
-------+------+------+------+---------+----------
| 201 |   1   |  11  |  20  |    71   |   73    |
| 203 |   1   |  13  |  20  |    80   |   87    |
| 204 |   2   |  10  |  21  |    72   |   75    |
| 206 |   2   |  13  |  21  |    76   |   78    |
| 208 |   2   |  12  |  22  |    72   |   78    |
| 209 |   2   |  13  |  22  |    76   |   80    |
| 210 |   3   |  11  |  23  |    73   |   71    |
| 211 |   3   |  12  |  23  |    71   |   77    |
| 212 |   3   |  13  |  23  |    78   |   81    |
| 213 |   3   |  10  |  24  |    70   |   81    |
| 214 |   3   |  11  |  25  |    71   |   82    |
| 215 |   3   |  12  |  26  |    74   |   83    |
| 215 |   3   |  13  |  27  |    78   |   80    |
```

RESULT

```
|  students  | FIS_1 | MAT_1 | KIM_1 | BIO_1 | FIS_2 | MAT_2 | KIM_2 | BIO_2 | FIS_3 | MAT_3 | KIM_3 | BIO_3 |
-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------
| student 20 |       | 71,73 |       | 80,87 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| student 21 |       |       |       |       | 72,75 | 76,78 |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| student 22 |       |       |       |       |       |       | 72,78 | 76,80 |       |       |       |       |
| student 23 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | 73,71 | 71,77 | 78,81 |
| student 24 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | 70,81 |       |       |       |
| student 25 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | 71,82 |       |       |
| student 26 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | 74,83 |       |
| student 27 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       | 78,80 |
```

Where **FIS_1, MAT_1,... FIS_2, MAT_2.., FIS_3, MAT_3**.. is **CONCAT** from TABLE B kode and TABLE A id,

and **value** *MAT_1, BIO_1*... is CONCAT from TABLE D value_m and value_n

It's Posible? How can I do that with GROUP_CONCAT mysql query? I've tried it but still not successful..

Thanks for your advance..

Comment: You mysql can use group_concat for value but not for column name ..

Comment: The link you posted gives a good example of how to do it.