# Create row as a column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following three tables and I want to so as last table using a stored procedure. Can anyone tell me how I can join them?

**Disc**:

```
DiscId  DiscName
1         a
2         b
3         c
```

**DiscDetail**:

```
DiscDetailId  DiscId  DiscDetailName  Percentage
1             1       p               5
2             1       q               10
3             2       r               12
4             2       s               11
5             2       t               13
6             3       u               19
7             3       v               20
```

**Pur**:

```
PurId  DiscId
1      1
2      2
3      1
4      1
```

I want to show data as follows:

```
PurId  p  q   r   s   t
1      5  10  
2             12  11  13
3      5  10
4      5  10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PurId ,
CASE WHEN DD.DiscDetailName ='P' THEN DD.Percentage END 'P',
CASE WHEN DD.DiscDetailName ='q' THEN DD.Percentage END 'q',
CASE WHEN DD.DiscDetailName ='r' THEN DD.Percentage END 'r',
CASE WHEN DD.DiscDetailName ='s' THEN DD.Percentage END 's',
CASE WHEN DD.DiscDetailName ='t' THEN DD.Percentage END 't'
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM DISC_DETAIL D
INNER JOIN  CHILD_TABLE CT ON DD.DiscId =CT.DiscId
)DD
```

Try above query.

Comment: There is Dynamic data of DiscDetail I can not Use Case When for p,q,r...

Comment: @user3405179 You can try according to below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns

Comment: This is also fix column I have dynamic columns.

Comment: Kindly check whole answer. First he made query for static column and then make for dynamic for same query.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic pivoting:

First declare all the columns :

```
DECLARE @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.DiscDetailName  ) 
                FROM DiscDetail c
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')
```

Create dynamic pivot:

```
set @query = 'SELECT PurId, ' + @Columns + ' from 
                (
                    select Pur.PurId
                        , DiscDetail.Percentage
                        , DiscDetail.DiscDetailName
                    from Pur 
                    inner join Disc on Pur.DiscID = Disc.DiscId  
                    inner join DiscDetail  on DiscDetail.ID = Disc.DiscId  
               ) x
                pivot 
                (
                     max(Percentage)
                    for DiscDetailName in (' + @Columns + ')
                ) p '


    execute(@query)
```