# mysql query sum values group by month but divided in years

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns: `ID`, `fieldDATE`, `fieldINT1`, `fieldINT2`.

Table is like this:

```
ID| fieldDate | FieldINT1 | FiledINT2 |

 ===================================

 1 |  2016-01-01   | 100    |  1     |

 2 |  2016-01-08   | 200    |  1     |

 3 |  2016-02-01   | 150    |  1     |

 4 |  2016-02-05   | 400    |  2     |

 5 |  2017-01-01   | 120    |  1     |

 6 |  2017-01-21   | 123    |  1     |

 7 |  2017-02-03   |  30    |  1     |

 8 |  2018-01-01   | 123    |  1     |

 9 |  2018-01-03   |  30    |  1     |
```

I'd like to create a table with 12 rows, with the first column is the month name, and the other columns are sum of `fieldINT1` and `fieldINT2`, group by month in a specific YEAR. So in my example, there will be 4 columns ( MONTH NAME, 2016, 2017, 2018)
How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns on the basis of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns)

Comment: Is it possible that you can return the values in a result set with the columns `month`, `year` and `sum`? This way the query is pretty simple, just a normal `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` statement.