# MYSQL convert row to column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Let's say that I have this one table which contain the student marks for each assessment (eg: quiz,test and etc).

This is the original table:

[image: studentmarks]

I wanted to convert the assessment type to be the column. This is the output that I want:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  student_name |  Quiz 1    |   QUIZ 2 |
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  thaqif       |  4.00      |   5.oo   |
+---------------+------------+----------+
|  ajis         |  4.00      |   5.00   |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

I am able to produce this with this algorithm:

```
SELECT  student_name,
        MAX(IF((`assessment_type` = 'QUIZ' AND `assessmet_no` = '1'), assessment_marks, NULL)) 'QUIZ 1',
        MAX(IF((`assessment_type` = 'QUIZ' AND `assessmet_no` = '2'), assessment_marks, NULL)) 'QUIZ 2'            
FROM    studentmarks
GROUP   BY student_name
```

However, in the real situation, the number of assessment type is unknown. The algorithm above is only useful if we have the fixed number of assessment_type.

In order to handle that, I have found an algorithm which I believed can solve the problem:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(`assessment_type` = ', `assessment_type`, ',assessment_marks, NULL)) AS ', `assessment_type`)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM studentmarks;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  student_name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM    studentmarks
                  GROUP   BY student_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Unfortunately, this algorithm called this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'QUIZ' in 'field list'
```

I have no idea on what's wrong with the algorithm. Fyi, I have gone through a few similar questions on SO but none of it seems to be working with my problem. These are some of the questions or information that I referred to:

1. [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns on the basis of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns)
3. [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only slightly more complicated than a regular pivot because you need a condition on two columns:

```
select student_name,
       max(case when assessment_type = 'QUIZ' and assesment_no = 1 then marks end) as quiz1,
       max(case when assessment_type = 'QUIZ' and assesment_no = 2 then marks end) as quiz2
from student_marks
group by student_name;
```

You can expand this into dynamic SQL as:

```
SET @condition = 'MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = ''@at'' AND assement_no = @an THEN assessment_marks END) as @at@an';

SELECT @conditions := GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(@condition, '@at', assessment_type), '@an', assessment_no))
FROM studentmarks;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT student_name, ', @conditions, ' 
FROM studentmarks
GROUP BY student_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I have tried the algorithm. However, it called another error: 

'Fatal error: Call to a member function getClauses() on null in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php on line 567'

Comment: Btw, if I remove the double quote from "@at". The same error #1054 - Unknown column 'QUIZ' in 'field list' is called

Comment: @MohammadThaqifTaher . . . Which statement causes that error?

Comment: This one:
`SET @condition = 'MAX(CASE WHEN assessment_type = ''@at'' AND assement_no = @an THEN assessment_marks END) as @at@an';`

Comment: @MohammadThaqifTaher . . . Assigning a string to a variable seems like a pretty mundane operation.  I have no idea what could be causing such an error.

Comment: The problem is ‘phpmyadmin’. Everything is okay when I changed to HeidiSQL.