# MySQL - Rows to Columns without declaring the name of the field value

Tags: mysql, sql

There was a solution provided by this thread: [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns). Yet I felt like it's not dynamic. I mean, what if people will add a new field value that hadn't declared? So the developer needs to change the query again in order to make it work? I don't want something like that. I want the query to last even when there are a lot of additional field values. 
Below is one of the procedures provided as answer.

```
 create view history_extended as (
  select
    history.*,
    case when itemname = "A" then itemvalue end as A,
    case when itemname = "B" then itemvalue end as B,
    case when itemname = "C" then itemvalue end as C
  from history
);

select * from history_extended;

+--------+----------+-----------+------+------+------+
| hostid | itemname | itemvalue | A    | B    | C    |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+------+------+
|      1 | A        |        10 |   10 | NULL | NULL |
|      1 | B        |         3 | NULL |    3 | NULL |
|      2 | A        |         9 |    9 | NULL | NULL |
|      2 | C        |        40 | NULL | NULL |   40 |
+--------+----------+-----------+------+------+------+
```

Let say, a new value - "D" has been added. The primary solution in order for the D values to be selected in query is to change the query and add a line: `case when itemname = "D" then itemvalue end as D`. And if another value has been added? It will never end. I need something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN itemname IS anything THEN itemvalue END AS anything FROM history;
```

> How to make a query that will make the thing possible? Please help.
>   Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with dynamic SQL.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You could search for mysql dynamic rows to columns - for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns

Comment: Those aren't dynamic. The query needs to compare the field value first before you make it as a column. What I exactly need is a query that will do the thing regardless of the field value, thus, it should not do the `case when item = 1 then price end` all over again.

Comment: I don't think you read (or understood) the full solution.

Comment: "Those aren't dynamic." @P.Salmon and Gordon Linoff are right in this situation.. You need to go dynamic SQL for this with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.. No other way possible in MySQL.