# Mysql Pivot Query / Suggestion

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

There is 3 tables

**Table User**

| user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-10-01 |
| 1002 | 2022-10-02 |
| 1003 | 2022-10-03 |
| 1004 | 2022-10-04 |
| 1005 | 2022-10-05 |

**Table Default_Properties**

| def_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | type_a | val_a |
| 11 | type_b | val_b |
| 12 | type_c | val_c |
| 13 | type_d | val_d |
| 14 | type_e | val_e |

**Table Custom_Properties**

| pro_id | fk_user_id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1002 | type_b | banana |
| 21 | 1005 | type_d | durian |

By default, every user will have default properties, unless overwritten with custom one. Thus, expected result as listed below:

**Expected Result**

| user_id | type_a | type_b | type_c | type_d | type_e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | val_a | val_b | val_c | val_d | val_e |
| 1002 | val_a | **banana** | val_c | val_d | val_e |
| 1003 | val_a | val_b | val_c | val_d | val_e |
| 1004 | val_a | val_b | val_c | val_d | val_e |
| 1005 | val_a | val_b | val_c | **durian** | val_e |

I tried to pivot it by using "case when" but have no luck to get the expected result. Highly appreciate for any query help/suggestion provided. Thank you!

Comment: Is `Default_Properties` only have 5 rows of records

Comment: Can be more than that, I simplify that for presentation purpose.

Comment: So this means the column number of the result is dynamic?

Comment: Yes it is dynamic one and there is over 30 rows. May assume it has only 5 rows of records now.

Comment: [mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964078/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns-on-the-basis-of-two-columns) might be helpful to your question

Comment: Thanks for your reference, @lucumt . Sadly, I don't see how the custom properties comes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_id,
  MAX(CASE d.type WHEN 'type_a' THEN COALESCE(c.value, d.value) END) AS type_a,
  MAX(CASE d.type WHEN 'type_b' THEN COALESCE(c.value, d.value) END) AS type_b,
  MAX(CASE d.type WHEN 'type_c' THEN COALESCE(c.value, d.value) END) AS type_c,
  MAX(CASE d.type WHEN 'type_d' THEN COALESCE(c.value, d.value) END) AS type_d,
  MAX(CASE d.type WHEN 'type_e' THEN COALESCE(c.value, d.value) END) AS type_e
FROM user AS u
CROSS JOIN Default_Properties AS d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Custom_Properties AS c ON u.user_id=c.fk_user_id AND c.type=d.type
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY u.user_id;
```

Output, tested on MySQL 8.0.29:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| user_id | type_a | type_b | type_c | type_d | type_e |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1001 | val_a  | val_b  | val_c  | val_d  | val_e  |
|    1002 | val_a  | banana | val_c  | val_d  | val_e  |
|    1003 | val_a  | val_b  | val_c  | val_d  | val_e  |
|    1004 | val_a  | val_b  | val_c  | val_d  | val_e  |
|    1005 | val_a  | val_b  | val_c  | durian | val_e  |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

It's not possible in SQL to do "dynamic columns."

Columns must be fixed at the time the query is parsed, which is before it has read any of the data in the table. So there's no way a query can expand the columns as it reads data, beyond those you name explicitly in the select-list when you write the query.

By analogy, this would be like calling a Java function whose name is the return value of the function.

So to do an effective pivot table, if the properties you want to make columns for may change, then you must do the query as two steps: first know the set of properties you want to make columns for. Something like the following would give you the list of properties:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM Default_Properties
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM Custom_Properties;
```

Then use the result of that query to build your pivot table query. (I.e. a loop of code, appending expressions to the select-list of a query as strings.)

Comment: OP has said the column in the expected data is dynamiclly,so it might be more than 6 columns

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill! Will try it out asap ;) Learned new stuff today, "cross join". Thanks lucumt too for clarification, if possible to works with dynamic data is the best, but this answer is good for me too ;)

Comment: See my additional content in my answer above.