# How to combine columns into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in one query: (there will always be 3 rows of contact data. Always)

```
name     phone
john     5551234
jane     3452345
paul     8475739
```

I have the following data in another query:

```
col1     col2     col3
data1    data2    data3
```

What I want to do is to add the first query to the second to obtain this:

```
col1    col2    col3    name1   phone1    name2   phone2    name3   phone3
data1   data2   data3   john    5551234   jane    3452345   paul    8475739
```

Comment: Read: [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns)

Comment: [Much better tutorial](http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf)

Comment: Thanks again, Grijesh. I'm going there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to create [pivot table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) from your query - and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns) is a common solution for that in MySQL.

But it's very unstable - much better to do proper formatting in your application since count of specific rows could be various, data could become inconsistent, e t.c. - so in general, this idea is not a good one.

Comment: Thanks Alma. I'm currently doing the formatting in the application code now but that is proving to be unstable as well. Sometimes I get the correct results and sometimes I don't. I thought I'd try to keep it all in a single query and see if that helped.