# count row values as column name mysql

Tags: mysql, select, row

I have table `user_completed`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_completed` (
  `rowId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(54) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


INSERT INTO `user_completed` (`rowId`, `designer_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, accept),
(2, 1, reject),
(3, 1, accept),
(4, 1, reject),
(5, 1, overtime),
(6, 2, accept)
(7, 2, accept)
(8, 3, accept)
(9, 2, reject);
```

Which look like:

```
rowId   designer_id    status 
1           1          accept
2           1          reject
3           1          accept
4           1          reject
5           1          overtime
6           2          accept
7           2          accept
8           3          accept
9           2          reject
```

I want to get result below:

```
designer_id   accept   overtime   reject
1             2        1          2
2             2        0          1
3             1        0          0
```

But I have no idea how to group `designer_id` then count distinct `status` and each into columns like above.

Comment: you can find lots of answers here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  designer_id,
    SUM(IF(status = 'accept',1,0)) as 'Accept',
    SUM(IF(status = 'reject',1,0)) as 'Reject',
    SUM(IF(status = 'overtime',1,0)) as 'Overtime'
FROM 
    user_completed
Group By designer_id
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c055/2)**

As [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) said It's simply workig with this

```
SELECT  designer_id,
    SUM(status = 'accept') as 'Accept',
    SUM(status = 'reject') as 'Reject',
    SUM(status = 'overtime') as 'Overtime'
FROM 
    user_completed
Group By designer_id
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c055/3)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it wil work

```
select designer_id, 
count(case status  when 'accept'then 1 else null end)as accept,
count(case status when 'reject'then 1 else null end)as reject,
count(case status when 'overtime'then 1 else null end)as overtime
from user_completed group by designer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many distinct `status` you have then you can check this link for solution

[Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns)

e.g you can use something like below

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
   CONCAT(
     'SUM(IF(`status` = "', `status`, '",1,0)) AS ', `status`)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM user_completed;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  designer_id, ', @sql, ' 
              FROM    user_completed
              GROUP  BY  designer_id');
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```