# How to display a result side by side

Tags: mysql

In SQL when i execute a query with projection of one column  from a "table A" am getting results set in three rows of that column , I need it in one row side by side.

Example

```
select rank from table A where name="RAMESH"
```

I have 1,2,3 ranks on the name "ramesh"
am getting result set as

```
RANK
----
1
2
3
```

but I need like this

```
RANK(1)  RANK(2)   RANK(3)
-------   -----  --------
1           2       3
```

Please help me out....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Go through this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns you will get a good idea.

Comment: Don't do it on database level, do it on application level.

Comment: I tried by rotating the monitor. But now text is seen down to up instead of left to right. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score -1):

Well this will probably work

```
WITH x AS (SELECT rank FROM table A WHERE name="RAMESH")
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 0, 1)as a,
    (SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 1, 1)as b,
    (SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 2, 1)as c
LIMIT 1;
```

You join the first column with the second and then the third

Comment: MySQL does not support common table expressions, and `LIMIT` without order by is not deterministic.

Comment: I used limit to make it faster in performance. Without LIMIT it will still work but you will have to ignore all the other rows except the first. As you can't use with you can make multiple selects.