# Row into column with unique heading in Mysql without using string functions

Tags: mysql

How do get I data from column which contains multiple values for a single record to show in new columns with custom heading, without using string function in MYSQL.

Here is a subset of table which I have pulled using multiple joins.

```
Product  | Category
-------- | ------------
MSI60000 | Sunglasses
MSI60000 | Minimal Coding
MSI60001 | Glasses
MSI60001 | Minimal Coding
MSI60002 | Sunglasses
MSI60002 | Short Coding
MSI60003 | Goggles
MSI60003 | Long Coding
MSI60004 | Goggles
MSI60004 | Shortcoded
```

I'm looking to achieve this from above table.

```
Product  | Type        | Coding
-------- | ----------- | --------------
MSI60000 | Sunglasses  | Minimal Coding
MSI60001 | Glasses     | Minimal Coding
MSI60002 | Sunglasses  | Short Coding
MSI60003 | Goggles     | Long Coding
MSI60004 | Goggles     | Shortcoded
```

Solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179803/create-view-and-convert-rows-into-column-in-mysql) kind of helped me however it uses string functions which I can't use.

Comment: What is the problem with string functions?

Comment: The system I'm using doesn't allow me to use string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query -

```
SELECT
  Product,
  MAX(IF(LOCATE('Coding', Category) = 0, Category, NULL)) AS Type,
  MAX(IF(LOCATE('Coding', Category) > 0, Category, NULL)) AS Coding
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  Product;
```

---

```
MSI60000    Sunglasses      Minimal Coding
MSI60001    Glasses         Minimal Coding
MSI60002    Sunglasses      Short Coding
MSI60003    Goggles         Long Coding
```

...but there is LOCATE function.

Comment: Thankyou! I can't target specific string here as column may contain unpredictable strings. Added another row in the end.

Comment: There is no way to understand which is type, which is coding for values like `Goggles | Shortcoded`. Only to compare strings.

Comment: In some cases it is possible to automate pivot - http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/