# Mysql / Mariadb query to dynamically convert rows to columns while querying the data

Tags: mysql, dynamic, pivot-table, dynamic-columns

I looked at the answers at [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns) but I could not get it to work because I need to join tables to get all of the information.  Can you please help me place the 'question' as the column name as shown here?

```
datestamp           pay        benefits ...    career advancement
---------------------------------------------------------------------   
2/16/2017 11:55     Somewhat   Slightyly       Slightly
2/16/2017 11:55     Agree      Somewhat        Very
```

The data looks like:

```
id  datestamp        survey_col           value
-----------------------------------------------
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ001    A3
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ002    A4
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ003    A4
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ004    A3
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ005    A2
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ006    A3
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ007    A4
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ008    A3
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ009    A4
1   2/16/2017 11:55 885457X234X1368SQ010    A1
```

I'm using this code:

```
   SELECT T.id, T.datestamp, SQ.question, 
      IF(type IN ("K", "N", "S", "T", "Y", "*") AND type NOT IN ("F"),
         T.value,
         IF(parent_qid = 0, SA.answer, SA2.answer)
      ) as answer
      FROM survey_questions SQ 
      JOIN survey_lookup SL ON SL.qid = SQ.qid
      JOIN tmp T ON T.survey_col = SL.survey_col
      LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA ON SA.qid = SQ.qid
         AND SA.code = T.value
         AND SA.language = 'en'
      LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA2 on SA2.qid = SQ.parent_qid
         AND SA2.code = T.value
         AND SA2.language = 'en'
      WHERE SQ.language = 'en'
      ;
```

Which provides:

```
id  datestamp       question                            answer
----------------------------------------------------------------
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Pay                                 Somewhat
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Benefits (health plan, leave, etc.) Slightly
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Career Advancement                  Slightly
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Access to Training                  Somewhat
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Leadership Style                    Very
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Manager/Supervisor Style            Somewhat
1   2/16/2017 11:55 Please enter comments               The company's policies...
```

This code worked when all of the data was in one table and I did not have to use joins.

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
   SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1000000;  -- default is 1024
   SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(question = ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''', answer, NULL)) AS ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''''
         )
      ) INTO @sql
      FROM tmp; 

      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT row_id, submitdate, ', @sql, ' FROM ', survey_report, ' GROUP BY row_id');

      IF DEBUG = 1 THEN
         SELECT @sql;   
      END IF;

      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This was an attempt without the REPLACE function (which I would like to use).

```
 SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT(
  'MAX(IF(SQ.question = ', '''SQ.question''',' 
      IF(type IN ("K", "N", "S", "T", "Y", "*") AND type NOT IN ("F"),
        T.value,
        IF(parent_qid = 0, SA.answer, SA2.answer)
      ) as answer, NULL)) as answer', '''SQ.question''')
  ) INTO @sql
  FROM survey_questions SQ 
  JOIN survey_lookup SL ON SL.qid = SQ.qid
  JOIN tmp T ON T.survey_col = SL.survey_col
  LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA ON SA.qid = SQ.qid
     AND SA.code = T.value
     AND SA.language = 'en'
  LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA2 on SA2.qid = SQ.parent_qid
     AND SA2.code = T.value
     AND SA2.language = 'en'
  WHERE SQ.language = 'en';  

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp GROUP BY id');

  SELECT @sql;   

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You probably already know this is called *pivoting* a table. You've discovered what a pain in the neck it is in MySQL.

Comment: I agree.  I'm using software that is very challenging to get the needed data.  I was using a cursor to get the data which was horribly slow but I discovered that unions made it much faster.  So, I used a union to get the data so I could create joins.  Now, I'm trying to get it to a format that I can use in graphing software.   I have tried several things and this seems to be the best because it runs in 11 seconds where other solutions I taken 4 minutes.

Comment: This is one of those times when SQL is the _wrong_ solution to the problem.  Write PHP/Java/whatever code to do the formatting.  Use SQL to provide the  data.

Comment: Thanks James.  I'm using JBoss Dashbuilder which I think is written in java so that is an option.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with java.  I could save the data to another table and then format it but I assume writing to the disk is slow.

Answer (score 0):

This worked but I did not want to create another table.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE  IF EXISTS `tmp2`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2
   SELECT T.id, T.datestamp, SQ.question, 
      IF(type IN ("K", "N", "S", "T", "Y", "*") AND type NOT IN ("F"),
         T.value,
         IF(parent_qid = 0, SA.answer, SA2.answer)
      ) as answer
      FROM survey_questions SQ 
      JOIN survey_lookup SL ON SL.qid = SQ.qid
      JOIN tmp T ON T.survey_col = SL.survey_col
      LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA ON SA.qid = SQ.qid
         AND SA.code = T.value
         AND SA.language = 'en'
      LEFT JOIN survey_answers SA2 on SA2.qid = SQ.parent_qid
         AND SA2.code = T.value
         AND SA2.language = 'en'
      WHERE SQ.language = 'en'
      ;
```

--    select * from tmp2;

```
         SET @sql = NULL;
   SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN = 1000000;  -- default is 1024
   SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(question = ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''', answer, NULL)) AS ''', REPLACE(question,"'", "\\'"), ''''
         )
      ) INTO @sql
      FROM tmp2;
      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, datestamp, ', @sql, ' FROM tmp2 GROUP BY id');

      SELECT @sql;   

      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```