# Mysql query to dynamically count the occurrences of a row and convert it to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I am querying a mysql database to summarize test execution results. My data looks something like this.

```
+-+------------+----------------+
id|test_case_id|execution_status
+-+------------+----------------+
1 |     1      |     passed
+-+------------+----------------+
2 |     2      |     failed
+-+------------+----------------+
3 |     2      |     passed
+-+------------+----------------+
4 |     1      |     passed
+-+------------+----------------+
5 |     2      |     failed
+-+------------+----------------+
```

How do I query this data to get this:

```
+-+------------+------+------
id|test_case_id|passed|failed
+-+------------+------+------
1 |    1       |  2   |  0
+-+------------+------+------
2 |    2       |  1   |  2
+-+------------+------+------
```

The closest I could find something is this thread: [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns). However, since I need to sum the occurrences of execution status, I can't quite get it to work. I cannot use a temporary table, dynamic SQL, or stored proc due to data source and destination considerations. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use conditional aggregation.  I don't know why you didn't find this in your searches:

```
select test_case_id, sum(execution_status = 'passed') as passed,
       sum(execution_status = 'failed') as failed
from t
group by test_case_id;
```

Comment: Oh boy, I was over-complicating things while missing the obvious. Thank you!